# loopback module for grub with secure boot

Tags: grub2

I am building a multi-boot usb stick with ubuntu derivatives. I followed several tutorials found online: essentially, you put the isos on a usb stick and then you boot them using grub, which is installed on the stick.

However, I have the following problem: my stick should work also with Secure Boot on. However, I need the loopback grub module to boot the isos, and when I boot with secure boot on, the secure boot forbids grub from loading the loopback module. So, I cannot boot

Has anybody been able to boot an iso from grub with secure boot on?

Thank you

valerio

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to work around this at the moment.

It looks like ubuntu's grub has been explicitly patched to prevent loading of modules during secure boot. The error message is slightly unhelpful: it confusingly references the filename, when the error occurs regardless of what module is being loaded:

```
apt-get source grub-common
   ...
grep -C 10 "Secure Boot forbids" -r .
   ...
#ifdef GRUB_MACHINE_EFI
  if (grub_efi_secure_boot ())
    {
      grub_error (GRUB_ERR_ACCESS_DENIED,
                  "Secure Boot forbids loading module from %s", filename);
      return 0;
    }
#endif
...
```

The patch that adds this is ./debian/patches/no_insmod_on_sb.patch

Your best bet is probably to rebuild grub either hardcoding loopback support or allowing the loading of modules, or maybe you can just disable secure boot when booting from usb (since this tends to be quite a rare activity).

The security implications of allowing grub to load modules are rather complicated, so I'm going to avoid commenting on them because someone will instantly tell me I'm wrong, and we'll have to have an argument.

Comment: That's an excellent answer. Even if it doesn't solve my problem : loading the modules for decrypting a root luks partition and then getting the root partition from lvm. Thank you for  your thorough research. I guess I'll roll my own ppa with a grub without those checks.

Comment: @Dolanor Did you ever roll your own PPA that I could use?

Comment: I'm sorry, no. I haven't taken the time to really make a nice package for it. It was harder to do it well enough for other people to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that current versions of the signed grub image (at least the one I've tested, which comes with Ubuntu 20.04) contain the `loopback` module, so there's no need to load/insert it. In fact, this is not possible, as already noted in the above answer. I'm posting the configuration I used in order to create an external drive which can boot an Ubuntu install/live environment and a Windows 10 installation.

I ended up using several partitions - a 512MB EFI, 20GB NTFS for the unpacked Windows files and a large FAT32 partition for everything else, including the Ubuntu ISO. The NTFS one is needed as Windows now includes installation files larger than 4GB. I don't think the signed grub image includes the exfat module at the moment, so NTFS is the only option here. As a side note, the unpacked Windows files must reside in the partition root, having them in a subdir didn't work for me.

Below is the configuration I used for installing grub to the EFI partition:

```bsh
sudo grub-install \
--boot-directory=[EFI mount point]/boot \
--efi-directory=[EFI mount point] \
--uefi-secure-boot \
--removable \
--target=x86_64-efi \
--no-bootsector \
/dev/sdaX
```

And here is the `grub.cfg` file (I think the lines above the first menu entry are redundant, but that's the actual config I used):

```bsh
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid [UUID of EFI partition]
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $root/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry 'Ubuntu 20.04.1' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {        
    set isodir='/images/ubuntu'
    set isoname='ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
    set isofile=$isodir/$isoname
    
    search --no-floppy --set=isodev --fs-uuid [UUID of FAT32 partition]

    loopback loop0 ($isodev)/$isofile
    linux (loop0)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet splash
    initrd (loop0)/casper/initrd
}

menuentry 'Windows 20H2' {
    set efi_path=/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
    
    search --no-floppy --set=windev --fs-uuid [UUID of NTFS partition]
    chainloader ($windev)/$efi_path
}

menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
    fwsetup
}
```

And that's all, I hope someone finds it useful.